# How to pass functions to RDD.map?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've been struggling with `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` but finally figured out how to make this work:

```
case class Article(id: Int, title: String, content: String) extends Serializable

 val index: RDD[(String, List[(Int, Int)])] = (for {
      article <- articlesRDD
      text = article.title + article.content
      word <- text.split(" ")
    } yield (word, (article.id, 1)))
      .groupByKey()
      .mapPartitions{
        _.map {
          case(k, v) => (k, v.groupBy(_._1).map(pair => (pair._1, pair._2.map(_._2).sum)).toList) // Works as expected
          //case(k, v) => (k, reducer(v.toList)) // Fails
        }
      }.cache()
```

And here is `reducer`:

```
def reducer(list: List[(Int, Int)]): List[(Int, Int)] = {
    list.groupBy(_._1).map(
      pair => (pair._1, pair._2.map(_._2).sum)
    ).toList
  }
```

I also tried defining the `reducer` function as a `val` but I'm getting the same error. Actually, the error occurs in a Databricks notebook, in my machine running Spark in local mode it works fine.

Why does the commented `case` statement fail ? 
Do I have to pass anonymous functions always even if they are not as trivial as my `reducer` function ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say *where* `reducer` is defined, but it's likely to be in a non-serializable class (e.g. the one containing `SparkContext` etc.). Then using it requires capturing the instance it's called on. Define it in an `object` instead.

From the [Spark Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/programming-guide.html#passing-functions-to-spark):

> Spark’s API relies heavily on passing functions in the driver program to run on the cluster. There are two recommended ways to do this:
>
> - Anonymous function syntax, which can be used for short pieces of code.
> - Static methods in a global singleton object. For example, you can define `object MyFunctions` and then pass `MyFunctions.func1`, as follows:
>
>   ```
>   object MyFunctions {
>     def func1(s: String): String = { ... }
>   }
>
>   myRdd.map(MyFunctions.func1)
>   ```
>
> Note that while it is also possible to pass a reference to a method in a class instance (as opposed to a singleton object), this requires sending the object that contains that class along with the method.

Comment: Actually, the error occurs in a Databricks notebook. In my machine running Spark in local mode it works fine. I'm sorry. Forgot adding that little detail.